# Merge every certain number of items in a list

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list like this

```
items= ['e', '4', 'e', 'e', '4', '5', '4', '8', 'a', '8', '6', 'd', '8', 'a', 'e', '1', 'b', '6', '2', '1', '6', 'a', 'a', 'a', '2', 'b', 'd', '6', '7', '7', '9', '2']
```

I want to edit the list so that every 4 items in the list get merged like this

```
items=['e4ee', '4548', 'a86d', '8ae1', 'b621', '6aaa', '2bd6', '7792']
```

Edit: My mistake for wording. By not creating a new list I meant by putting the arranged elements into a separate list like this

```
items = ['e', '4', 'e', 'e', ...

items2 = ['e4ee', '4548', ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks) with an added string join

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new list and then just assign its reference to *items*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this although this does create a new list:

```
items = ['e', '4', 'e', 'e', '4', '5', '4', '8', 'a', '8', '6', 'd', '8', 'a', 'e', '1', 'b', '6', '2', '1', '6', 'a', 'a', 'a', '2', 'b', 'd', '6', '7', '7', '9', '2']

items = [''.join(items[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(items), 4)]

print(items)
```

**Output:**

```
['e4ee', '4548', 'a86d', '8ae1', 'b621', '6aaa', '2bd6', '7792']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Maybe I just worded incorrectly but what this is what I mean by not creating a new list.

Answer (score -1):

If you absolutely **do not** want to create a new list (as stated):

```py
result_len = len(items) // 4
for i in range(result_len):
    j = (i*4)
    items[i] = ''.join(items[j:(j+4)])
for i in range(len(items) - 1, result_len - 1, -1):
    del items[i]
```

Does exactly `len(items)` iterations and never creates a new list.

The first loop updates the first `result_len` items in the list to the desired values. The second one deletes the rest of the items from it.

EDIT: Whoops, had a bug there. Now it should be correct.

Comment: This does not produce OP's required output